# Trying to update Rocket.rs managed state with error - cannot assign to data in dereference of `rocket::State<Timer>`

Tags: rust, state, dereference, rust-rocket

I am new to rust and I am trying to update some Rocket state in a request handler.

Here is an example of my code:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Timer {
    playing: bool,
    paused: bool,
    start_at: AtomicUsize,
}

[post("/message", data = "<form>")]
fn message(form: Form<Message>, timer: &State<Timer>) {
    timer.start_at.store(time, Ordering::Relaxed); // this is fine
    timer.playing = true; // errors are here
    timer.paused = true; // and here
})

// launch rocket
...
let _rocket = rocket::build()
        .manage(Timer {
            start_at: AtomicUsize::new(0),
            playing: false,
            paused: false,
        })
        .mount("/", index)
        .launch()
        .await;
...
```

The error I am getting is:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to data in dereference of `rocket::State<Timer>`
   --> src/main.rs:311:29
    |
311 | ...                   timer.paused = false;
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign
    |
    = help: trait `DerefMut` is required to modify through a dereference, but it is not implemented for `rocket::State<Timer>`
```

Is there a way to make this state mutable within this request handler?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**
This is what Rocket.rs say about managed state:

> Note: All managed state must be thread-safe. Because Rocket
> automatically multithreads your application, handlers can concurrently
> access managed state. As a result, managed state must be thread-safe.
> Thanks to Rust, this condition is checked at compile-time by ensuring
> that the type of values you store in managed state implement Send +
> Sync.

However, I am not sure how to make this state thread-safe with Send + Sync.

Comment: Wrap the whole state in an `Arc<Mutex<…>>`, or use atomics (like you already do for `start_at`).

Comment: Thanks @Jmb, I used `AtomicBool` and that did the trick.